# How to block some websites in google chrome browser while using ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: bash, firefox, google-chrome

I am using ubuntu 14.04, I want to block some websites in Google Chrome and Firefox. What should I do?

Comment: It will halp you. Before ask something try to find answer in internet. https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Customize-controls-options-and/Block-and-unblock-websites-with-parental-controls-on-Firefox/ta-p/984

Comment: You can block certain websites in all browsers by editing the `hosts` file: [How to block any site?](//askubuntu.com/a/491399)

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the /etc/hosts file, but this will block the website(s) on every browser, not just Chrome.  Look for the following line:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Add a line for every site you want to block.  For example:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       blockedwebsite.com
127.0.0.1       anotherwebsite.com
```

Changes should take effect immediately.

Please be cautious when editing the hosts file.  Also, these changes are for IPv4 only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adblock Plus or Ublock origin browser plug-ins in order to block sites, then use custom filter for the partial website.